# Flutter how to save data locally while phone screen is off

Tags: flutter, hive

I wanna save data locally while app running in background and phone screen is off , how can u do that using hive DB.

I just try to save data locally while app is running everything is fine now I want to do the same thing while screen phone is off

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Hive supports opening boxes in multiple isolates, so you will have to close the box in the main isolate, update it in your background isolate and reopen it in the main isolate.

[This](https://medium.com/@lelandzach/dart-isolate-2-way-communication-89e75d973f34) might help

Here is an example code of communication between two isolates:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

Future<SendPort> initIsolate() async {
  Completer completer = new Completer<SendPort>();
  ReceivePort isolateToMainStream = ReceivePort();

  isolateToMainStream.listen((data) {
    if (data is SendPort) {
      SendPort mainToIsolateStream = data;
      completer.complete(mainToIsolateStream);
    } else {
      print('[isolateToMainStream] $data');
    }
  });

  Isolate myIsolateInstance = await Isolate.spawn(myIsolate,isolateToMainStream.sendPort);
  return completer.future;
}

void myIsolate(SendPort isolateToMainStream) {
   ReceivePort mainToIsolateStream = ReceivePort();
   isolateToMainStream.send(mainToIsolateStream.sendPort);

   mainToIsolateStream.listen((data) {
     print('[mainToIsolateStream] $data');
     exit(0);
   });

   isolateToMainStream.send('This is from myIsolate()');
}

void main() async {
  SendPort mainToIsolateStream = await initIsolate();
  mainToIsolateStream.send('This is from main()');
}
```